# Can you specify multiple cookie paths?

Tags: weblogic, peoplesoft, cookie-path

I'm developing in PeopleSoft and the you access the PIA portal through a URL such as https://mywebserver.com/**psp**/ps/EMPLOYEE/CRM/?cmd=login.  However, at some integration points, it will go through the non-portal URL https://mywebserver.com/**psc**/ps/EMPLOYEE/CRM/?cmd=login.  Notice how both are at the root level.

If I set cookie-path=/psp then the URL through /psc won't work correctly and vice versa.

For a clean PEN test, is there a way Weblogic can be set up to allow multiple values for a cookie path?  I'm trying to achieve something like this in the weblogic.xml:

```
<session-descriptor>
  <cookie-path>/psc;/psp</cookie-path>
</session-descriptor>
```

Comment: The cookie-path attribute only supports a single path according to the documentation. What would be the argument against using just "/"?

Comment: The PEN test report flagged a path of / as a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can out of the box.

The best way to solve this would be to write the set-cookie directive directly in a servlet.

A hack that might work: assuming you set the cookie path of PeopleSoft to "/psp" and a user approaches the domain over the /psc path WebLogic should return a faulty "set-cookie" with the /psp path. You could catch that in your webserver and rewrite the header to /psc. In Apache this would be something like "Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)/psp(.*)$ $1/psc$2" in the context of the /psc .

Comment: That is an interesting approach, will take some regression effort though.  I appreciate the tip!